# How much two columns match based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, percentage

If my dataframe looks like this:

```
user   item   real   value  predict
  u1     i1    0.0    0.31      0.0
  u2     i1    1.0    0.50      0.0
  u1     i2    0.0    0.27      0.0
  u3     i2    0.0    0.91      0.0
  u1     i3    1.0    0.71      1.0
  u3     i3    0.0    0.80      1.0
```

How can I determine how accurate `predict` is compared to `real` for every single user? So for example:

```
u1   1.00
u2   0.00
u3   0.50
```

I was thinking of grouping by users, splitting the dataframe into multiple where the user is the same, transform those two columns into lists and then see how much they match. But I have thousands of users. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: could you group by users and do the following for each group take the (sum{df['reral') - sum(df['predict'])/sum(df['real'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Since it's a classification problem, would work.

Create another column `Diff` which is True if `real` and `predict` match, False otherwise; then `groupby` on `user` and find the mean value of `Diff` for each `user`:

```
out = df.assign(Diff=df['real']==df['predict']).groupby('user')['Diff'].mean()
```

Output:

```
user
u1    1.0
u2    0.0
u3    0.5
Name: Diff, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sklearn` you could easily use `mean_squared_error`

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mse = df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x['real'], x['predict']))
acc = 1 - mse
print(acc)

# Output:
user
u1    1.0
u2    0.0
u3    0.5
dtype: float64
```

**Note**: if you can't or don't want to use `sklearn`, use instead:

```
mean_square_error = lambda r, p: (np.linalg.norm(r-p)**2)/len(r)
```